# How does this code work and what is it called

Tags: c++, c, i2c

The code in question is "? something : something_else". Usually in the code below you can put either I2C_SLAVE or I2C_SLAVE_FORCE. But this code does something else. How does it work and what exactly does it do?

```
if(ioctl(state.i2c_bus_address, force ? I2C_SLAVE_FORCE : I2C_SLAVE, add) < 0)
{
    logger.fail("i2c select fail %d",add);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That's a "ternary operator"  or "conditional operator". It's basically similar to an `if`/`then`/`else`, except that it yields a value, so something like `a = b ? c : d;` gives roughly the same result as `if (b) a = c; else a = d;`. It's probably used most often in C macros, because it can execute as a single expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the ternary conditional operator. It's like an if, but inline. Here's the format

```
boolean ? result evaluated to if true : result evaluated to if false
```

Here's an example:

```
y = x>2 ? 12 : 5;
```

If x is greater than 2, y will be 12, otherwise y will be 5.

Comment: It is a ternary operator, meaning it takes 3 arguments. In the same way that a binary operator takes 2 arguments, and a unary operator takes one argument, but this operator's name is the "conditional operator". Wink-wink-nudge.

Comment: You know, despite there being only one, I'll go with the verbose definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Other_operators

Comment: One important difference between the ternary operator and an if statement, which you demonstrated but did not explicitly state, is that the ternary operator returns a value.  Upshot is that you can initialize a variable with a ternary operator.  This is especially important for references or const objects, which must be initialized.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher +1, I can live with that.

Answer (score 3):

It's name is "conditional operator".

```
condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

If **condition** evaluates to true, then evaluate **expression1**, otherwise evaluate **expression2**.

Comment: +1, its proper name is the conditional operator, and it happens to be ternary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but the `statement ? if_true : if_false` control flow is called the ternary operator.

The `statement` is evaluated. If it's true, the expression after the `:` is evaluated. Otherwise, the expression after the `:` is evaluated.